# sqldeveloper taking too long to load the content of a DB

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working with Ubuntu 18.04. After installing sqldeveloper I correctly log in and get a list of databases. Upon doubleclicking on one database to show its content sqldeveloper becomes extremely slow. I receive the following message right after double clicking on a DB:

`UsersCache.fillIn() time = 4  ret==null?: true`

And then it takes approximately 10-15 minutes to load the database I clicked. After that time I can interact with the DB, but if I want to open another one I have to wait about the same time. The size of the DB is big, but on my colleague's machines it is a matter of seconds. I tried to uninstall and install it again but there is no way it speeds things up. Running it in verbose doesn't give more info than the one-liner I pasted above.

EDIT: `top` shows a CPU usage of approximately 180% on the sqldeveloper process.

Comment: it is _not_ caching the db locally.  run this and get a stack of what it's doing:jstack <PID>

Comment: List of databases? Are you working with sybase or SQL server?

Comment: What exactly are you double clicking on, the connection? That will open the connection, is that what is taking a long time?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes, that's it. The list of the left shows the various connections. I double-click on one and have to wait a long time before it loads. Working with sqldeveloper

Comment: @KrisRice you can find part of what I found on jstack here https://pastebin.com/9yfCnKvN

Comment: It’s your java and gnome not getting along. Are they both current ?

Comment: GNOME 3.28.1 and `java -version` returns `java version "1.8.0_171"`. Inspecting with `top` shows I'm using `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` to run sqldeveloper

Comment: we do NOT support openjdk

Comment: Thank you for specifying that, through `update-alternatives`I selected `java-oracle` but apparently it fell back on `openjdk`... so I updated it in the config and now it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @thatjeffsmith if you'd like, you can post an answer that I can mark as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inspecting with top shows I'm using java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 to run
>   sqldeveloper

That is likely your problem. We do not support OpenJDK (or IBM's either for that matter.)

For the best experience we recommend and ONLY support the Oracle JDK - specifically, version 8.

I noticed on our download pages we do not say this specifically, but do point folks to the Oracle downloads for Java. I'll add a note/disclaimer so it is more obvious.

You can control the Java Home used or SQL Developer in the .sqldeveloper directory in your $HOME. There is a product.conf file in there, put the path to Oracle JDK 8 there.

Comment: At \sqldeveloper\bin\jdk.conf add or edit the line SetJavaHome /path/jdk, for example for windows will be the SetJavaHome c:/jdk

Comment: For future readers, on my windows machine I found "product.conf" (at C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\19.2.0\product.conf) and (as an example) changed this line "SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8" to "SetJavaHome C:\MyProgFiles\Oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\jdk" .  Note the double quotes are mine and you will not have them.  Obviously, your Oracle JDK needs to exist.  @thatjeffsmith can you verify my (new) jdk path looks like a legitimate one?j  My "javac -version" reports back "javac 1.8.0_171"

Comment: yeah you're telling sqldev to use the JDK that shipped with your DB - so it's going to be OLD, but it'll work. For now.

Comment: Slightly different question, but you know a lot more about this than I do.  :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067331/can-oracle-express-run-with-a-different-runtime-or-jdk-other-than-the-value-set