# Can Oracle Express run with a different runtime or jdk other than the value set by JAVA_HOME

Tags: oracle-xe

I've installed Oracle XE.

When I ran sqldeveloper.exe against it, sqldeveloper.exe ran "slow" against my local XE database AND remote Oracle database engines.

I found this answer:

[sqldeveloper taking too long to load the content of a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941020/sqldeveloper-taking-too-long-to-load-the-content-of-a-db/50968538#50968538)

After I made that fix, sqldeveloper.exe ran pretty dern good against the REMOTE oracle database engine.

However, running it against the local XE, it still runs poorly.

My machine environment variable to set to a Zulu install and cannot be changed (company policy)

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8
```

So my question is.. can I alter which JDK oracle.exe runs with?

Here is my version:

```
c:\mycustomfolder\oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomexe\bin\ORACLE.EXE XE
```

I found this .conf file

```
C:\mycustomfolder\Oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\schagent.conf
```

but don't see any place to override the JDK runner, like I found for sqldeveloper.exe.

Comment: the database ships it's own JDK to use - you should NOT change that...now, generally, running queries against the XE database will NOT invoke any Java code in the db. If running SQL Developer against the XE on your machine is slow, try increasing the amount of memory to the XE db

Comment: Ok, XE is using its own path to the JDK it installed (which makes sense).....it just isn't "exposed" as a setting.  Since it wasn't exposed, I wasn't sure if it was using JAVA_HOME in the background somewhere.  The funny thing is that I pointed sql-developer (the link in my question to the other SOF question) to the JDK that XE was using. (C:\mycustomfolder\Oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\jdk)  At least now they're in sync!  Thanks again.

Comment: @jeff  If you put your comment (first one) as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database ships its own JDK to use - you should NOT change that...now, generally, running queries against the XE database will NOT invoke any Java code in the db. If running SQL Developer against the XE on your machine is slow, try increasing the amount of memory for the XE database itself ([SGA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-27A013E8-66E2-483B-83A4-76DE10E3DADD)).

Comment: For future readers who stumble upon this question ....... another (very) small tip, start Oracle XE (or is it Oracle EE) (Express Edition) (the "Oracle" prefixed windows services in windows world)... start them on demand instead of as an autoservice.  (example net start OracleServiceMYLETTERS)   See http://www.rebellionrider.com/slow-windows-startup-after-oracle-installation/  you can also restart the oracle services if you haven't rebooted in a while.  Again, small tips... Memory tip from this answer is much better.